# this.call is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For the life of me, I can't see what I'm missing.  I had hard-coded the value for selectedIcon in the drawmenu function.  It was working perfectly until I changed it to a parameter.  I'm getting the following error:

> Error: this.call is not a function
>
> Source File:
>   http://localhost:9090/tests/jquery-1.3.2.min.js
>
> Line: 19

The routine is drawing a menu, while dynamically adjusting spacing between images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
        Test image overlay
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        function drawmenu (selectedIcon) {

            var offset = 0;
            for (x in icons) {
                // Add the gap at the top of the image
                if (selectedIcon-1 == x) {
                    offset += icons[x].topBig;
                    $("#"+icons[x].divid).toggleClass("active");
                    $("#"+icons[x].imgid).toggleClass("rollit");
                } else {
                    offset += icons[x].topSmall;
                }

                // Set the location of the image
                $("#"+icons[x].divid).css("top",-offset);

                // Add the gap at the bottom of the image
                if (selectedIcon-1 == x) {
                    offset += icons[x].bottomBig;
                } else {
                    offset += icons[x].bottomSmall;
                }
                $("#"+icons[x].imgid).attr("src",icons[x].image);
            }
        }

        var icons = [
            {
                "divid"       : 'icon1', // Home
                "imgid"       : 'imgicon1',
                "image"       : 'home.png',
                "topSmall"        : 5,
                "topBig"          : 5,
                "bottomSmall" : 5,
                "bottomBig"   : 7
            },{
                "divid"       : 'icon2', // Alert
                "imgid"       : 'imgicon2',
                "image"       : 'alert.png',
                "topSmall"    : 7,
                "topBig"      : 13,
                "bottomSmall" : 0,
                "bottomBig"   : 0
            },{
                "divid"       : 'icon3', // Question
                "imgid"       : 'imgicon3',
                "image"       : 'question.png',
                "topSmall"    : 4,
                "topBig"      : 8,
                "bottomSmall" : 5,
                "bottomBig"   : 7
            },{
                "divid"       : 'icon4', // Lightbulb
                "imgid"       : 'imgicon4',
                "image"       : 'lightbulb.png',
                "topSmall"        : 3,
                "topBig"          : 7,
                "bottomSmall" : 5,
                "bottomBig"   : 7
            },{
                "divid"       : 'icon5', // Blog
                "imgid"       : 'imgicon5',
                "image"       : 'blog.png',
                "topSmall"        : 3,
                "topBig"          : 6,
                "bottomSmall" : 1,
                "bottomBig"   : 4
            },{
                "divid"       : 'icon6', // Defect
                "imgid"       : 'imgicon6',
                "image"       : 'defect.png',
                "topSmall"        : 7,
                "topBig"          : 10,
                "bottomSmall" : 0,
                "bottomBig"   : 0
            }]

        $(document).ready(drawmenu(6));
        //]]>
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        #iconstack {
            position: absolute;
            top:30px;left:100px;
        }
        .icondiv { z-index:1; position: relative;}

        .active { height:80px; }

        .rollit {
            height:50px;
        }

        .rollit:hover {
            background-image:url('highlight.png');
            background-color:red;

        }

        /*]]>*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="iconstack">
    <div id="icon1" class="icondiv">
        <img id="imgicon1" class="rollit" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="icon2" class="icondiv">
        <img id="imgicon2" class="rollit" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="icon3" class="icondiv">
        <img id="imgicon3" class="rollit" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="icon4" class="icondiv">
        <img id="imgicon4" class="rollit" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="icon5" class="icondiv">
        <img id="imgicon5" class="rollit" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="icon6" class="icondiv">
        <img id="imgicon6" class="rollit" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the error? Perhaps use Firebug or your browser's debugging tools to trace back the call chain. That error happens inside jquery, but it would be instructive to know where in your code the call into jquery first happens.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's actually a minor issue. What you were previously doing was this:

```
$(document).ready(drawmenu);
```

which passed a function. What you're now doing is this:

```
$(document).ready(drawmenu(6));
```

The 2nd way is passing the RESULT of the function instead of the function itself, and is equivalent to:

```
var item = drawmenu(6);
$(document).ready(item);
```

Try instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ drawmenu(6); });
```

Comment: Thanks!  It makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is way down near the bottom with this line.

```
$(document).ready(drawmenu(6));
```

What your need is this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    drawmenu(6);
});
```

Basically instead of passing a function to .ready you're passing whatever returns from the drawmenu function.

Comment: Well I did write this answer 3 minutes ahead of the one you chose. I am not quite sure how his answer is better.

Comment: It looked to me like his was first.  Regardless, while I understood both answers, I think the example of why the code looked right, but was still wrong will be helpful to new coders.  The Heath brothers call it "The curse of knowledge."  It's in their book: Made to Stick.  It's a great read.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling drawmenu instead of passing it as an argument to jQuery's ready function. The fix is to create a new function and pass that function to jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { drawmenu(6); });
```